# How to hide redmine header and footer for a specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I need to show a page without redmine header and footer inside an iframe. Please help me !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" including the links. We need more detailed information from you in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added this line (The header and the footer disappeared ; Only the content has been loaded):

```
render :layout => false
```